# Inserir dado com Entity e sem campo identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho esse método para inserir no banco:

```
public virtual void Inserir(T item) 
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().Add(item);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

E tenho isso em minha entidade Produto, por exemplo:

```
.......
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int IdProduto { get; set; }
.......
```

Veja que o `DatabaseGeneratedOption` é `None` e não `Identity`, isso eu fiz, porque o campo não é `Identity`, achei que não poderia colocar por essa razão e nem sei se incrementaria, mas fiz assim, para acompanhar o banco no cliente, que não tem Identity em nada. Como eu faria para o campo ID ir incrementando à medida que eu vou inserindo. Não quero fazer gambiarra, para pegar o `atual + 1`, isso não quero fazer. `T` é do tipo `class`

Comment: ou é o max + 1, ou é gerado no banco, outro jeito nunca vi

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, bom dia. Eu não tenho identity no banco, mas se na minha classe, eu fizer isso `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, vai incrementar, mesmo esse campo no banco não ser identity?

Comment: @pnet Não, você tem as duas opções que o Rovann disse.

Comment: @LINQ, valeu. Nesse caso terei que usar o Max + 1 mesmo, até porque no banco do cliente não tenho identity.